# Replacing a 7.2 volt battery pack

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I have a dead battery from my Tivoli Pal radio that I wish to replace. It is a NiMH 7.2V 1400mAh like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0043GGDGC) (the mAh being the only difference I guess).

Would it be safe to take the connector off the battery pack with <strike>four</strike> two of [these](http://www.dx.com/p/ultra-fire-10440-3-6v-500mah-2pack-974) in serial connection? Would that give me the same end result?

Comment: Only if your current end result is that the device goes up in flames.

Comment: I'll add my unpopular view: If you know the peak current and voltage from your NiMH charger to be within safe levels for your new Li-Ion, then no problem. The charging caracteristics arn't that different. I've designed battery chargers for years. On the other hand, if your NiMH goes too high in voltage, you will probably set you battey pack on fire.

Comment: @winny: I'm sure you can match Lithium batteries to a NiMH charger reasonably well if you know exactly what you're doing. But here we have a NiMH charger designed for 7.2V, and four 3.6V Lithium cells in series. The cells would be constantly undervoltage and AFAIU rapidly develop cathode dendrites that will short them out internally, rendering them unable to hold a charge, and also convert most of the current to heat during charging. I'm not saying that something remotely like this can't be done, I'm just saying that the OP should not proceed with the plan suggested in their original question.

Comment: Oh!  Sorry, I completely overlooked the difference in voltage.  I thought we just wanted to change one battery for type to another.

Comment: For what it's worth I meant to use two of the batteries I linked to, not four. It would just add up in total to four of the individual AA-sized units.

Comment: @schwifty In a 2S2P-configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not safe. Never charge Lithium batteries with a charger that is designed for NiMH, unless your goal is to set things on fire, spectacularly.

It is of course possible to replace or redesign the charging circuit, but the easiest and arguably safest route would be to replace your old NiMH batteries with some new NiMH batteries.

Comment: Alright then, good thing I asked. So two of [these](http://www.dx.com/p/rechargeable-3-6v-aaa-800mah-ni-mh-battery-pack-100986) might work?

Comment: Looks like that would work. You could also buy six LSD NiMH cells of the right size (AA or AAA?), cut open the old battery pack, and replace each cell. Might be cheaper, give you a better fit in the battery compartment, and lets you reuse the original connector.

Comment: That was my original plan, but I thought I might be able to shrink the battery package a bit without losing battery capacity.

Comment: Possibly, but cheap Chinese batteries are often overrated, sometimes grossly so. I would rather buy brand name batteries with realistic ratings if I were you. They give better real-world performance and longevity in my experience.